# apply formula vertically by using row

Tags: excel-formula

This is my sheet

[image]

on the cell E1 I'll have

```
=A1*B4
```

How can I copy this formula to E2 and E3?

E2 should have `A2*C4` and E3 should be `A3*D4`

I tried `INDEX( COLUMN())` but couldn't success.

Thank you very much

Comment: Anywhere in the first row `=$A1*INDEX($4:$4,,ROW()+1)` i.e. not in `A1:D1`.

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=A1*INDEX($4:$4,,1+ROW())` and drag down.

Or in Office365 you could use this to spill the result: `=A1:A3*INDEX($4:$4,,SEQUENCE(3,,2))`

Comment: The results should be `1, 4, and 9` in `E1:E3`, yet your formula returns `3, 4, 3, 0, and 0` in `E1:E5`. I'm sure there is a simple fix.

Comment: My bad. I misread the question. Thought the second cell needed to change from right to left. Updated my answer.

Comment: and I marked it as answer. thank you and @VBasic2008